# how to make http request to webserver in c#

Tags: c#, http, post, web

Hi i need some help on this.
I have one web server and i must request information+header from it.I must send to webserver file.txt then server read from file first ID and return information to me about this ID.
I will put in file.txt ID: 1,2,3 ... n , and server will respone me infromation for every ID.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please take a look at the [System.Net.WebClient](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.webclient%28v=vs.80%29.aspx) class